# Sort two columns of data and keep the non-duplicate values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, unpivot

I have an issue with sorting two columns of data (with duplicates). The details are as follows:

```
A   B
2   3
1   4
3   5
4   6
6   2
...
```

I want to sort data in Column A and Column B and only keep the non-duplicate values. The expected result should be in Column C (Column A and B data should not be removed):

```
C
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
```

Excel function is preferred as I need to avoid using VBA for the file.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: It's unfortunate you can't use VBA because it would extremely easy with macros. All you need to do is copy both ranges into 1 column C. Then sort C, and use the remove duplicates function

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know can use VBA to do this, but only use excel functions cannot? As I have to build a macro-free file...@Silenxor

Comment: Then you're looking at array formulaes and fancy footwork using offset functions. You would need to have column C first combine the two ranges into 1 column using offset and ROW(). You can use Large or Small to sort the data in the column after that, then a couple of array formulas to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with a PivotTable, assuming your `A` and `B` are in Row1 and `2` and `3` are in Row2:

•   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+D, P to call up wizard.
•   Select Multiple consolidation ranges and PivotTable, <kbd>Next</kbd>.
•   I will create the page fields, <kbd>Next</kbd>.
•   For Range: select A1:Bn, <kbd>Add</kbd>, B1:Cn, <kbd>Add</kbd>, <kbd>Next</kbd>.
•   For Existing worksheet enter `=C1`, <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
•   Select PT and empty Column Labels and Σ Values entries.
•   Right-click PT, left-click PivotTable Options…, select Totals & Filters and uncheck Grand Totals.
•   Enter `C` in C1.